# RSpec controller test - ActionController::UnfilteredParameters: unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In my Rails 6 app I'm trying to test controller methods which allow admin users to update user data without providing user passwords. All actions are run in ActiveAdmin.

`admin/users.rb`

```
  controller do
    def update
      model = :user

      %w[password password_confirmation].each { |p| params[model].delete(p) } if params[model][:password].blank?

      super
    end
  end
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/testing-your-activeadmin-controllers-with-rspec) page I tried to write specs:

`admin/users_spec.rb`

```
  describe 'PUT update' do
    let(:user) { create(:user, :random_email) }

    let(:valid_attributes) do
      ActionController::Parameters.new(
        {
          user: {
            email: 'michael.kelso@example.com',
            password: '',
          },
        },
      )
    end

    before do
      put :update, params: { id: user.id, user: valid_attributes }
    end

    it 'update user' do
      expect(user.reload.email).to eq('michael.kelso@example.com')
    end
  end
end
```

What should I do to have this test green?

Answer (score 0):

you can still add strong params for activeadmin.
Using method permit_params method like: `permit_params :title, :content, :publisher_id`

activeadmin strong param docs:
https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters

this post is related to this one: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md#setting-up-strong-parameters